# What are the subobjects of a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, category-theory

Categorically a subobject of an object $a$ of some category $A$ is an object $a'$ with a monic morphism to $a$, ie $a'\to a$, upto isomorphism.

When $A$ is either a Topological or Differential manifold, what are the subobjects of a manifold, and are they the same as submanifolds?

**edit**

My own thinking on this is that in the smooth category one ought to work with manifolds together with the tangent bundle structure and then epics turn out to be surjective submersions and monics, injective immersions. These being very useful notions in the wider context of manifold theory.

Comment: That depends. What morphisms are you choosing?

Comment: @Yuan: The real intent of the question is how to categorically select the 'usual' submanifolds, ie embeddings, immersed submanifolds etc which from peoples comments seem to require Diff being concrete; and to see whether the usual categorical subobjects result in anything useful here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category of topological (resp. differential) manifolds.
The objects of $\mathcal{C}$ are topological(resp. differential) manifolds and the morphisms of $\mathcal{C}$ are continuous(resp. smooth) maps.

Let $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism in $\mathcal{C}$.
We claim $f$ is a monomorphism if and only if $f$ is injective.

Suppose $f$ is a monomorphism.
Let $x, y$ be distinct points of $X$.
Let $p$ be a $0$-dimensional object in $\mathcal{C}$.
There exists the unique morphism $g\colon p \rightarrow X$ such that $g(p) = x$.
Similarly, there exists the unique morphism $h\colon p \rightarrow X$ such that $h(p) = y$.
Since $g \neq h$, $fg \neq fh$.
Hence $f(x) \neq f(y)$.
Hence $f$ is an injective map.

Conversely, suppose $f$ is injective.
Clearly, $f$ is a monomorphism.

---

"Are they the same as submanifolds?"

Generally no.

**Counter-example:**

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be the map defined by $f(x) = (x^3, 0)$.
$f$ is smooth and injective but is not an immersion($f'(0) = 0$).
Hence $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be identified with a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $f$.

Comment: +1 Well explained! Perhaps it might be helpful for some less experienced readers if you would specify the objects and morphisms in the categories of topological/differential manifolds.

Comment: I always learned that a map isn't considered smooth if the derivative is ever zero.  Otherwise, you could make a path with corners and call it "smooth" by having all its derivatives be zero at each corner.

Comment: @MartianInvader If you don't allow a smooth function to have the zero derivative, you can't call a constant function smooth. In your case, a path with corners is not differentiable at the corners. Regards,

Comment: @Kato: From what I understand, an immersion implies locally the image is a submanifold. From this it doesn't follow that if it isn't an immersion then the image cannot be locally a submanifold. It seems to me it could go either way?

Comment: @MoziburUllah An injective immersion is identified with the canonical injection of a submanifold.
Conversely the canonical injection of a submanifold is an immersion. Regards,

Answer (score 8):

Monic morphisms are injections in concrete categories like the category of manifolds, so a subobject of a manifold $M$ is another manifold with an injection into $M$.  This isn't quite the same thing as a submanifold, as usually submanifolds are required to be *embedded*, meaning that they inherit their topology from the larger manifold.

For an example of a manifold that is injected into a larger manifold but isn't embedded, let $M$ be a torus (considered as a quotient space of $\mathbb{R}^2$ under integer translations), and let $L$ be the real line, mapped to a line of irrational slope in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and then projected to the torus.  This causes the line to "wrap around" infinitely without touching itself.  This map is an injection, thus $L$ with this map is a subobject, but the image isn't a manifold, since any neighborhood of a point contains infinitely many "nearby" lines.

Edit: As pointed out below, I was erroneous when I said monic morphisms are injective in all concrete categories.  It is true for manifolds, however, as proved in Makoto Kato's answer.

Comment: Ok, so to get an embedded manifold, we must stipulate that it has the initial topology wrt to the injection. That works for topological manifolds, but not for differential manifolds.

Comment: "Monic morphisms are injections in concrete categories" This is not true in general.

Comment: A sufficient condition for a concrete category $C$ to have the property that the monics are precisely the injective morphisms is that the forgetful functor $C \to \text{Set}$ is representable. This is true for the category of manifolds and for many other common concrete categories, but is false in general. In general we can only conclude that injections are monic.

Comment: @MakotoKato Thanks for pointing out my mistake, I've noted it in the bottom of the answer.
To MoziburUllah: Yes, in the differentiable category you also require that the map is an immersion.  I can't actually come up with with a smooth injective map of manifolds that isn't an immersion off the top of my head, though.

Comment: @MartianInvader As for an example of a smooth injective map of manifolds that is not an immersion, please see my answer.